# Matrix multiplication behavior in NumPy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Have the following:

```
In [14]: A = array([[1, 1], [3, 2], [-4, 1]])

In [15]: A
Out[15]:
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 3,  2],
       [-4,  1]])

In [16]: x = array([1, 1])

In [17]: x
Out[17]: array([1, 1])

In [18]: dot(A, x)
Out[18]: array([ 2,  5, -3])
```

I was expecting a column, because dot() function is described as an ordinary matrix multiplication.

Why does it return a row instead? This behaviour seems very discouraging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` a 1D vector, and as such has no notion of whether it's a row vector or a column vector. Same goes for the result of `dot(A, x)`.

Turn `x` into a 2D array, and all will be well:

```
In [7]: x = array([[1], [1]])

In [8]: x
Out[8]: 
array([[1],
       [1]])

In [9]: dot(A, x)
Out[9]: 
array([[ 2],
       [ 5],
       [-3]])
```

Finally, if you prefer to use more natural matrix notation, convert `A` to `numpy.matrix`:

```
In [10]: A = matrix(A)

In [11]: A * x
Out[11]: 
matrix([[ 2],
        [ 5],
        [-3]])
```

Comment: I just wanted to point out that using 1d vectors can be quite convenient because numpy will let you, in general, use a 1D vector as either a column or row vector. Of course you can you should use 2d arrays to store vectors if you need to distinguish between the column and row vectors.

Comment: In more detail: 1-D vector is the mathematical object `{a_i: i=0..N-1}` and matrix product `b = A*a` is defined as `b_i = sum_j A_ij a_j`. In general, it often matters little whether a vector is column or row, so it's more convenient to use the 1-D tensors instead. Also, using `numpy.matrix` is discouraged as your code becomes context-dependent for that case (i.e. whether `A*B` is an elementwise or matrix product depends on the types of `A` and `B` -- this makes just a mess in the long run).

Comment: @pv. do you suggest not to use matrices, and use arrays all the time? It seems code will be quite verbose with all this dot()'s.

Comment: @Deshene: yes, having A.dot(B) instead of A*B is a bit more verbose, but in the long run you are better off avoiding having the meaning of `*` depend on what the operands happen to be.

Comment: Python 3.5 lets you shorten the former to `A @ B`.